# How to calculate datetime in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would like to make a booking application
one field there is date and time
for example: long time of booking and reservations

date of booking : 18-12-2013 15:30:00
And long booking : 6 hours

And the result will be 18-12-2013 21:30:00

what if the date of the message and the old order. hours ended up being 0:30. it's already changed the day or date.

date of booking : 18-12-2013 20:30:00
And long booking : 5 hours

And the result will be 18-12-2013 01:30:00

how to implement it in PHP?

sorry i'm still newbie :-)

my php code

```
$date_booking = $_POST['datebooking'];

$long_time = $_POST['long']; // its contents were 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on

$result = strtotime($date_booking) + $longtime;
```

Comment: Start reading [PHP's date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), try coding some and come back here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` to change your date string into an integer (number of seconds since 1970-01-01 ).

Convert the long booking from hours to seconds (*60*60), then do the addition and use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $endTime)` to convert back to a datetime string.

Note: you will have first to transform your string "DD-MM-YYYY" into "YYYY-MM-DD" to make this works

**EDIT** with your code:

```
$date_booking = $_POST['datebooking']; // need to be formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS" (for example) 
$long_time = $_POST['long']; // its contents were 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on
$long_time_sec = $long_time * 3600; // convert hours to seconds
$result = strtotime($date_booking) + $long_time_sec; 
echo 'end of booking is '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $result);
```

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: In the code you added in your question, you use `$long_time` and `$longtime`. replace `$longtime` by `$long_time * 60 * 60` and you will have you example :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `strtotime` that accepts dates with different formats and where you can add some amount of time. In your case you can do:

```
$mydate = strtotime("18-12-2013 15:30:00 + 6 hours");
```

Then you have a number of seconds from 1970-01-01 (UNIX time) and you can convert to any format you want with `date` function:

```
$returnValue = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $mydate);
```

**NOTE**: I haven't understand if you have "text orders" like *date of booking : XXXX And long booking : X hours*. If this is the case, you can use the function `str_replace` or similar to get rid of the 'date of booking : ' and 'And long booking :' part:

```
$order = str_replace(array('date of booking : ', 'And long booking :'),
                     '',
                     $order);
```

Answer (score 0):

New PHP code should make use of the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) functions. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with strtotime(), but DateTime will handle things like DST changes for you with no bother. In this case your code should be something like this:-

```
$date_booking = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $_POST['datebooking']);
$long_time = new \DateInterval("PT{$_POST['long']}H");
$date_booking->add($long_time);
echo "Booking ends at " . $date_booking->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See a working example](http://3v4l.org/4I2Kf).

Read more about formatting DateTime [here](http://php.net/date).